# Using Query command to extract, compare and list data

Tags: spreadsheet

I run a music festival and the data given by the ticketing provider is extremely poorly laid out, in a spreadsheet format with vertical merges. From this data, We use google Sheets to extract camping tickets from other festival ticket types and then allocate camping tent numbers. The proposed solution is:

1: Extract camping tickets using Query commmand:

```
=QUERY(TicketData!A1:S50000, "Select C,D,E, F, G,N, S where I contains 'Season Shared Camping - 10 man tent'Order By C").
```

But the Query command must also:

2: compare results with a static sheet of existing allocations

3: Only display entries that are not also in static existing allocations sheet.

Thus the Query command now shows only new, unallocated camping ticket purchases which need to be actioned. Once placed in the static sheet, the entry will be automatically removed from the query sheet as it now exists in both sheets.

Unique Identifier is column C, and the column which contains the text string which identifies if it is a camping ticket is column S.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you have that downvote due to this not being an excel question, but it being tagged as so. Either way I think I have a solution.

Writing complicated requirements into a query string can sometimes be quite tough as it usually requires escaping the string and weaving in cell references etc. What you can do is do part of the work in the 'data' section of the Query formula and then use the query string to select just the columns you want.

I've done this by using =FILTER and COUNTIF:

**Step 1:** Filter the TicketData using the 'Season Shared...' string and the Static values with:

```
=FILTER(TicketData!A:S, TicketData!I:I = "Season Shared Camping - 10 man tent", COUNTIF(TicketData!C:C, Static!C:C) > 0)
```

**Step 2:** Tie this into the Query, substituting the above Filter for the data section of the Query. We need to refer to columns as Col1, Col2 etc so it will look like this:

```
=QUERY(FILTER(TicketData!A:S, TicketData!I:I = "Season Shared Camping - 10 man tent", COUNTIF(TicketData!C:C, Static!C:C) > 0), "select Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col14, Col19")
```

I tried this on some mock data and it worked for me. Let me know how you get on.

**Edit:** After looking at the data in the comment it looks like my Filter needs some altering as the Static list is a different length to the other filter data. I got round this by concatenating all the static IDs together (comma separated) and then using the FIND formula. If it doesn't find anything it is picked up by the ISERR formula and comes through in the filter:

```
=QUERY(FILTER(TicketData!A:S, TicketData!I:I = $C$2, ISERR(FIND(TicketData!C:C, CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(Shared!A:A&","))))), "select Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col19")
```

You can see this working on the public data you provided by [clicking here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19DqNaeRPNwbi_0qWOkhSccZZh2PDDNz82GScCLbfAac/edit#gid=1343700615)

Comment: Thanks. We'll try this solution. The issue would be that there are 4 types of camping tickets, So each time we do a ticket sales data dump into the spreadsheet we would need to change the filter statement and update each tent allocation sheet respectively.

Comment: Filter statements can take multiple conditions. Could you not add each of the 4 types to the filter? Alternatively you could make the Filter condition reference a control cell (e.g. B1) which has all 4 ticket types in a data validation list like this: '=FILTER(TicketData!A:S, TicketData!I:I = B1.....",'

Comment: Here's a public test copy
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16uaIA9W08ksYyDgI9knZHIl--n3aQq5mMcW373H8NQ0/edit?usp=sharing

I'll have a try. I'm not a programmer.

Comment: @Malius Try this [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19DqNaeRPNwbi_0qWOkhSccZZh2PDDNz82GScCLbfAac/edit#gid=1343700615) Change the ticket type in the yellow cell on the _experiment_ sheet. It needed to be done slightly different because the Static numbers range is different so I concatenate it and then use find. If it can't find it then it adds it to the list.